# Mysql query in the for loop

Tags: mysql, loops, for-loop

I used "for" loop to enter data into the database. However, some data is not saved into the database. I expected that 25 datas were saved. but I can see only 17 datas are entered in the database. 
I wonder why this happen? How can I fix this problem?  Please let me know. Thank you for advance.

```
for ($i= 1; $i <26 ;$i++){ 
 $url="page".$i."";
 $page=file_get_contents($url);

    $Divider="line";

    $divide=explode($Divider, $page);

    $p1=$divide[0];
            $p2=$divide[1];


    $query1 = "INSERT INTO table (page1, page2 )VALUES ( '$p1', '$p2' )";
    mysql_query($query1);

}
```

Comment: well your for loop only goes to 25, so how are you supposed to 100?

Comment: I don't understand like @stewbydoo pointed out your loop just goes from 1 to 25, so you couldn't possibly get 100 insertions and neither 17?

Comment: Could you post the table schema as well.

Comment: sorry about the typo..

Comment: I agree with Ben, please add the table schema. I don't see any obvious reason for some of the INSERTs to fail. I would also check the return code on the mysql_query() call. If it returns false, perhaps you can printout which INSERTs are failing.

Comment: For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

Comment: I echo the variable $p1. Some of them are not showed and not saved in database too.

Comment: You're attempting to read 25 files using $i as part of the filename. Have you verified that all of those files exist? My guess is there are 8 that don't exist which is causing $p1 and $p2 to not get set and then the insert fails.

Comment: table shema is      page1 text latin1_general_ci    page2 text latin1_general_ci